# React useParams undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am doing a personal `React.js` project. I am having issues with `useParams`. One of the issues that I am facing is that I cannot find a common id for the `useParams`. I am not able to show on screen the items that I pass as props in `ItemDetails`. This is the `ItemContainer`.:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import ItemDetails from "../Itemdetails";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const showRace = async (raceId) => {
  const res = await fetch("https://www.betright.com.au/api/racing/todaysracing");
  const json = await res.json().result;
  const race = Object.keys(json).find((findKey) => findKey === String(raceId));

  if (!race) {
    throw new Error("No match found.");
  }
  console.log('race in showRace', race)

  return race;
}

const ItemContainer = () => {
  const [venue, setVenue] = useState({});
  const { raceId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    showRace(raceId)
      .then((races) => {
        setVenue(races)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('error useEffect itemContainer', error)
        setVenue({});
      })
  }, [raceId]);
  console.log("venue container", venue);

  return <ItemDetails key={raceId} venue={venue} />;
};

export default ItemContainer;
```

This is the ItemDetails:

```
const ItemDetails = ({ venue }) => {
  console.log("venue itemDetails", venue);
  return (
    <>
      {Object.entries(venue).map(([key, value]) => (
        <div key={key}>
          <h1>{key}</h1>
          {value.slice(0, 5).map((i, races) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <p>{races.Venue}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default ItemDetails;
```

This is a link to a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-http-mg13b?file=/src/components/ItemContainer/index.jsx) with the whole code.

Comment: This seems like the same issue/question as your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549797/react-useparams-gives-empty-object-when-goes-to-page)? Adding a `console.log({ raceId` });` correctly logs a passed `raceId`.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese yes, it is. But, because I updated the code and perhaps someone was working on it, I just created a new post.

Comment: Ok, please add any new relevant details to your newer question.