# React useParams gives empty object when goes to page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-router, react-router-dom

I am doing a personal `React.js` project. I am having issues with `useParams`. I cannot display map items after clicking on the navbar. It goes to the page, but not able to show on screen. It shows an empty object on screen. This is the `ItemContainer` where I defined `useParams` and I think has an error on the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import ItemDetails from "../Itemdetails";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ItemContainer = () => {
  const [venue, setVenue] = useState({});
  const { raceId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.betright.com.au/api/racing/todaysracing")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(
        (data) => {
            setVenue(data);
          console.log("data useEffect", data);
        },
        (err) => {
          return console.error(err);
        }
      );
  }, []);
  console.log("venue container", {venue});

  const para = Object.keys(venue).find((findKey) => findKey === raceId);
  console.log('para', para)

  return (
      <ItemDetails key={para} venue={venue} />
  );
};

export default ItemContainer;
```

This is the `ItemDetails` where I want to display the item:

```
const ItemDetails = ({ venue }) => {
    console.log('venue itemDetails', venue)
    return (
        <> 
        {venue.slice(0, 5).map(races => (
            <>
            <p>{races.Venue}</p>
            <p>Race Number: {races.Race1?.RaceNumber}</p>
            </>
        ))}
        </>
    );
}
 
export default ItemDetails;
```

This is Navbar:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from './Navbar.module.css';

const Navbar = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("https://www.betright.com.au/api/racing/todaysracing")
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(
          (data) => {
            setResult(data);
            console.log("data useEffect", data);
          },
          (err) => {
            return console.error(err);
          }
        );
    }, []);
    console.log("result of Navbar", result);
    
    return (
        <>            
            <div className={styles.navbarContainer}>
                <NavLink to='./races' 
                className={styles.navbarHome} 
                style={({ isActive }) => ({
                  color: isActive ? '#fff' : '#f4f4f4',
                  background: isActive ? '#7600dc' : '#7600dc',
                })}>Home</NavLink>
                {Object.entries(result).map(([key, value]) => (
                    <div className={styles.navbarItems} key={key}>
                        {value.slice(0, 1).map((i, race) => (
                            <NavLink 
                                key={i}
                                to={`/race/${key}`}
                                style={({ isActive }) => ({
                                    color: isActive ? '#fff' : '#d3d3d3',
                                    background: isActive ? '#7600dc' : '#7600dc',
                                    textDecoration: isActive ? 'none' : 'none'
                                    })}>{key}</NavLink>
                        ))}                            
                    </div>                                  
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

This is App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <Router>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/races' element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/races" />} />
                <Route path="/race/:raceId" element={<ItemContainer />} />
            </Routes> 
        </Router>
        
    </>
  )
}
```

This is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/joaquinpalacios-bet-right-7r3ci?file=/src/components/ItemContainer/index.jsx) to codesandbox with the whole code.

### UPDATE

This is a mock of the data. The original from the API has all different values, only the keys of Throughbred, Harness and Greyhound are a common thing for the useParams that have found. This is a new [link with the whole code plus the data mocked](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-2733x?file=/src/data/index.js:2609-2618). Below you can find the mock up data as well:

```
    const data = {
      Throughbred: [
        {
            VenueID: 674,
            Venue: "Santa Anita Park",
            Race1: {
              EventTypeId: 1,
              EventId: 6177745,
              VenueId: 0,
              Venue: null,
              CountryCode: null,
              RaceNumber: 6,
              AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641036900000)/",
              ResultStatusId: 0,
              SecondsToJump: 609,
              HasFixedMarkets: false,
              IsOpenForBetting: false,
              MarketShortcuts: null,
              Results: null,
              MasterCategoryName: null,
              EventName: null,
            },
            CountryCode: "USA",
            MasterCategoryName: "Overseas-Racing",
          },
          {
            VenueID: 674,
            Venue: "Santa Anita Park",
            Race1: {
              EventTypeId: 1,
              EventId: 6177745,
              VenueId: 0,
              Venue: null,
              CountryCode: null,
              RaceNumber: 6,
              AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641036900000)/",
              ResultStatusId: 0,
              SecondsToJump: 609,
              HasFixedMarkets: false,
              IsOpenForBetting: false,
              MarketShortcuts: null,
              Results: null,
              MasterCategoryName: null,
              EventName: null,
            },
            CountryCode: "USA",
            MasterCategoryName: "Overseas-Racing",
          }
        ],
    
      Harness: [{
        VenueID: 674,
        Venue: "Santa Anita Park",
        Race1: {
          EventTypeId: 1,
          EventId: 6177745,
          VenueId: 0,
          Venue: null,
          CountryCode: null,
          RaceNumber: 6,
          AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641036900000)/",
          ResultStatusId: 0,
          SecondsToJump: 609,
          HasFixedMarkets: false,
          IsOpenForBetting: false,
          MarketShortcuts: null,
          Results: null,
          MasterCategoryName: null,
          EventName: null,
        },
        CountryCode: "USA",
        MasterCategoryName: "Overseas-Racing",
      },
      {
        VenueID: 674,
        Venue: "Santa Anita Park",
        Race1: {
          EventTypeId: 1,
          EventId: 6177745,
          VenueId: 0,
          Venue: null,
          CountryCode: null,
          RaceNumber: 6,
          AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641036900000)/",
          ResultStatusId: 0,
          SecondsToJump: 609,
          HasFixedMarkets: false,
          IsOpenForBetting: false,
          MarketShortcuts: null,
          Results: null,
          MasterCategoryName: null,
          EventName: null,
        },
        CountryCode: "USA",
        MasterCategoryName: "Overseas-Racing",
      }
    ],
      Greyhound: [
        {
            VenueID: 674,
            Venue: "Santa Anita Park",
            Race1: {
              EventTypeId: 1,
              EventId: 6177745,
              VenueId: 0,
              Venue: null,
              CountryCode: null,
              RaceNumber: 6,
              AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641036900000)/",
              ResultStatusId: 0,
              SecondsToJump: 609,
              HasFixedMarkets: false,
              IsOpenForBetting: false,
              MarketShortcuts: null,
              Results: null,
              MasterCategoryName: null,
              EventName: null,
            },
            CountryCode: "USA",
            MasterCategoryName: "Overseas-Racing",
          },
          {
            VenueID: 674,
            Venue: "Santa Anita Park",
            Race1: {
              EventTypeId: 1,
              EventId: 6177745,
              VenueId: 0,
              Venue: null,
              CountryCode: null,
              RaceNumber: 6,
              AdvertisedStartTime: "/Date(1641036900000)/",
              ResultStatusId: 0,
              SecondsToJump: 609,
              HasFixedMarkets: false,
              IsOpenForBetting: false,
              MarketShortcuts: null,
              Results: null,
              MasterCategoryName: null,
              EventName: null,
            },
            CountryCode: "USA",
            MasterCategoryName: "Overseas-Racing",
          }
        ]
}
export default data;
```

Also, this is a screenshot of the `console.log(result)`
[image]

Comment: that Codesandbox is not working for me, the API is returning an error

Comment: Hi @LuisMontoya I just checked and it works fine. This is the same link: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-vaughan-070ug

Comment: which page are you are having a problem? `/race/:raceId` ?

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios I am having same problem as Luis, I got empty result on the api. My guess, we're still on 1st of Jan, but you in Australia already move on to 2nd of Jan? So the `/racing/todaysracing` got no result.

Comment: probably the API is restricting access based on my location/IP https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VarRt1fJKC4NRkidGKuz3Bp_F2N-OIXX/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I just updated the link. It weird as it works fine for me  in codesandbox and in my pc.

Comment: Hi @Doppio it seems it's that. I could't figure it out. Thanks. I believe the issue is in ItemContainer. It redirets fine on /race/:raceId but on that page shows only the navbar.

Comment: CSB doesn't work, seems your API endpoint is restricted so it's not pulling any data for us. The `raceId` route param is working, so I can only assume it's the API not returning data or your `Object.keys(venue).find((findKey) => findKey === raceId)` logic that is incorrect. You can mock the `"https://www.betright.com.au/api/racing/todaysracing"` data response for us in the CSB and we can debug from there.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese I just did a mock of the data. This mock has a repeated pattern, but the original from the API every value is different. The only common thing is the key. This is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cherry-2733x?file=/src/data/index.js

Comment: So I'm gathering you want to take the `raceId` route match param and filter the "data" to the matching venue by some property? What is the `raceId` in the "data"?

Comment: @DrewReese raceId is an ‘id’ that I created for the useParams in the ItemContainer file.

Comment: Right, that much is obvious. I'm asking *what* in the "data" correlates to the `raceId` route param. In other words, what are you attempting to match on so you can pass a "venue" object/value as a prop to `ItemDetails`?

Comment: Sorry @DrewReese I want to match the keys ‘Thoroughbred’ ‘Harness’ and ‘Greyhound’. Thanks so much for your interest.

Comment: Each of those values is an array. Is the array what you want to pass along, or is there a specific array element (*venue object*) you want to pass along as a prop?

Comment: @DrewReese I just added a screenshot of the console.log with all the data to the post. Exactly, I'd like to pass the whole array of Thoroughbred’ ‘Harness’ or ‘Greyhound'. And then display it on the screen through ItemDetails

Comment: Where's the code that matches that screenshot? It seems to have correctly accessed the "data" to get the object keys for use in the links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240645/discussion-between-joaquin-palacios-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few issues in how you are processing the response data.

Navbar

The data is an object where each property is a single key (*a race classification?*) with value that is the array of venues. Simply map the keys to links.

```
{Object.keys(result).map((key) => (
  <div className={styles.navbarItems} key={key}>
    <NavLink
      to={`/race/${key}`}
      style={({ isActive }) => ({
        color: isActive ? "#fff" : "#d3d3d3",
        background: isActive ? "#7600dc" : "#7600dc",
        textDecoration: isActive ? "none" : "none"
      })}
    >
      {key}
    </NavLink>
  </div>
))}
```

ItemContainer

Assuming the `fetch` functions correctly and the `venues` state is updated to the correct value the issue here is you are searching through only the keys, returning only the key instead of the array value. Here you can simply use the `raceId` as the dynamic key to access the venue array.

```
const para = venues[raceId] ?? [];

...

return para.map((venue) => <ItemDetails key={venue.VenueID} venue={venue} />);
```

[image: Edit react-useparams-gives-empty-object-when-goes-to-page]

[image]

Comment: Hi Drew. Thanks for you help. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Navbar works fine the way I had it. I mean, it goes to /race/greyhound or any of the others. When I tried your code, it breaks the code.

Comment: Hi Drew. I apologise. I double checked the mock of the data and it had a mistake. It's fixed now. The whole data is an Object.

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios Ok, updated my answer and CSB. Please do take another look when you can.

Comment: Thanks Drew. Navbar works perfect, however when I click on an item of the navbar it crash with the change in itemcontainer. It works as before if I do not modify Itemcontainer. The error on screen says: TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Also, the console.log of 'para' is undefined

Comment: Each one of Throughbred, Harness and Greyhound has many arrays. So, the idea is to display in the screen (ItemDetail) all the content of Throughbred, Harness or Greyhound depending on what the user clicks. For that VenueID wouldn't work and I am trying to use the key Throughbred, Harness and Greyhound to match raceId of useParams.

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios I'm not sure I understand what your new issue is. I'm using the data you provided and it's working and rending without issue in the codesandbox I've provided. If `para` is undefined in your code that means `venues[raceId]` is undefined which means `raceId` from the route ***isn't*** a valid property in the data you're fetching and saving into the `venues` state. Are you *sure* you've provided us the correct response value?

Comment: Hi Drew. Pity my codesandbox doesn't work for everyone to see it. I may re do the whole post and try to clarify for future readers as well. My original issue is still being the same though. When I click in any of the items of the navbar it doesn't render the items in ItemDetail, even though on that page I have a console.log with the items inside.

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios Just mock the `fetch` function to return the `data` object you're updating state with, then we should see exactly what your code is trying to do with it. In other words, remove the data fetching from the equation so the code is only working with the rendering from state part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240647/discussion-between-joaquin-palacios-and-drew-reese).